# In swiftUI, How to remove ONLY safe area of NavigationBarTitle?

Tags: swift, swiftui

[image]My Objective is embedding `navigationBaritems`(for buttons) at the same line with `nabigationBarTitle`(for title). But `navigationBarTitle` goes underline of the `navigationBarItems.`

So Instead of using navigationBarTitle, I modified code like this: navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Title"), trailing: Button(action: {}) {Text("Button1")})

Now title and button are aligned at the same line, but the problem is a safe area of `NavigationBarTitle`.

**Things I have tried:**
I tried to remove it by using `navigationBarHidden(true)` But it removes all of `navigationBarItems` and esgesIgnoringSafeArea removes the `safearea` of `navigationBarItems` also. And also considered using `displaymode: .inline` but it doesn't look good.

How can I remove only the `safearea` of navigationBarTitle here?

My current code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {



        NavigationView{
            VStack{

                HStack{
                Text("dd")
                    }.frame(width: 500, height: 300)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                Spacer()

            }
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Title"), trailing: Button(action: {
                //some action
            })
            {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("dd")
            }
            .frame(width: 500, height: 300)
            .background(Color.blue)
            Spacer()
        }.padding(.top, 88)  // <--- adjust to your needs
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Title"), trailing: Button(action: {
                //some action
            })
            {
                Text("Button")
            }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)   // <--- add this

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes I think SwiftUI can be non-intuitive, but here are some suggestions:

Try putting the following line after your `.background(Color.blue)` line:

```
.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
```

Change the title to a non-empty string to see what `.inline` is doing.  Try taking the `, displayMode: .inline` out too.  That big title is what's trying to fill all the empty space you're seeing atop your VStack.  You can also experiment with `.navigationBarHidden(true)` if you want a custom nav bar (although you probably don't want that, but still interesting to try).

Edit:  I know you said you tried some of those things.  The key is **where** you put that line I list above.  It needs to modify an element inside the VStack (like your HStack or Spacer), so like I said, put that line below the one where you set the HStack's background color to blue.  It's trying to put an empty title above your HStack, which is what you're not wanting.